# last directory accessed by the user using volatility3

Tags: computer-forensics, volatility, memoryanalyzer

Using volatility3, How can I find the last directory visited by the user in windows?
In volatility2 we were able to find such thing using Shellbags plugin. But how can I do this in volatility3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shellbags plugin.

```
volatility -f <filename> --profile=<profile-name> shellbags
```

Comment: OP states volatility3 explicit, you mention volatility2